# Iterate through captures with boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a regular expression to capture three fields in a HTML tag using boost::regex

`"\\/\\/(.{1,3}?)\\.wikipedia\\.[a-z]+\\/wiki\\/(.*?)\\s*>(.*?)<"`

So, from

`<a href=\"//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porky%E2%80%99s\" title=\"Porky’s – German\" lang=\"de\" hreflang=\"de\">Deutsch</a>`

I get

- de
- Porky%E2%80%99s" title="Porky’s – German" lang="de" hreflang="de"
- Deutsch

But I´d like to have {de, Porky%E2%80%99s, Deutsch} instead.

How can I make my regex to stop matching the second field as soon as it finds the first white space?

I tried

`"\\/\\/(.{1,3}?)\\.wikipedia\\.[a-z]+\\/wiki\\/(\\S*?)*>(.*?)<"`

So the second field matches everything but whitespace but I get this crash report

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> >'
  what():  Ran out of stack space trying to match the regular expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work -

`"//(.{1,3}?)\\.wikipedia\\.[a-z]+/wiki/([^\\s>\"]*).*?>(.*?)<"`

I would use this instead -

`"//(.{1,3}?)\\.wikipedia\\.[a-z]+/wiki/([^\\s>\"]*)[^>]*>(.*?)<"`

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 //
 ( .{1,3}? )                   # (1)
 \.
 wikipedia
 \. 
 [a-z]+ 
 /wiki/
 ( [^\s>"]* )                  # (2)
 [^>]* 
 >
 ( .*? )                       # (3)
 <
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 9 , len 98 ) 
//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porky%E2%80%99s" title="Porky’s – German" lang="de" hreflang="de">Deutsch<  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 11 , len 2 ) 
de  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 33 , len 15 ) 
Porky%E2%80%99s  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 99 , len 7 ) 
Deutsch
```